# Call didSelectRowAtIndexPath only for a part of the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UITableView populated with many custom UITableViewCells. Each of them has a colored rectangle as a subview (currently it is a stylized UIButton but I can implement it anyway necessary).

I want the UITableViewCell to call `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` only when that part is selected.

Other similar questions asked how to get subviews to ignore events. But this would not work for me because selecting anywhere outside that rectangle would also trigger it.

I am not sure whether to limit the area of the cell that triggers the method or to disable triggering from the cell and instead allow the subview to trigger the method. Either way, I do not know the details of the implementation.

Comment: Why don't you use the button action method?

Answer (score 2):

In didSelect get your cell (passed to you), and check to see if the button in that cell is selected. If it is then do what you need, otherwise ignore it.

Comment: Oh that is a clever way, thank you! But, how would I check if the button was pressed? Also, is there a way of making it highlight only the button and not the whole cell? For example, look at the Settings app (or any app with a master-detail template). When you press a cell, it highlights, then segues to another view controller. and when you hit back, it segues back and also keeps the highlighted cell until the segue animation is complete and then it de-highlights it. Is it possible to get that behavior with only the rectangle and not the whole row? Thanks for the prompt answer!

Comment: When the button is pressed do [button setSelected: YES];  to see if it is selected do button.isSelected;  (do the opposite to deselect). But make sure you link the selected with your datasource, otherwise dequeing cells may move buttons around.  To "highlight" button, you can change the color, or image for the button (for default state, or selected state). This can also be done in interface builder

Comment: What would happen if the user presses the button, moves thumb to right (off of button) and lets go? Is there a way to take action only if the button was pressed and let go?

Comment: Sorry for so many comments. How would I do [button setSelected: YES]? I would have to put a target method for the button, right? And if I do this, didSelectRowAtIndexPath will not get called. The only way it would be called is if we disable the ability to select the button (making it "event transparent" as I heard some people call it)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath: but if you want to receive touch events from the button you can connect the button pressed event(touch up inside) to the table view controller if you have subclassed it or connect it to the table view controller's delegate if you have delegated it. If you need to actually select the row then you can call `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` and select the row programmatically when the button is pushed.

Comment: If I do that second implementation, it would not prevent the user from selecting the row outside of the button. The problem with the first one is that I may lose any extra behavior that one gets from the delegate method didSelectRowFromIndexPath. I am not very fluent with ios, so I am not sure. What are all the things that the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method does that I would not get if I just made it call my own target method? For example, look at my comment for @WilliamFalcon , will I still get that behavior with my own method?

Comment: The whole idea of delegate methods is that they are a place for you to add custom behavior. If you don't delegate it, it will behave normally. You can call the selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: manually if you are concerned that there is some other side affect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered not calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and instead creating an action for the `UIButton` to trigger when it is touched? I am not sure exactly what you want to do when when the `UIButton` is touched but lets say you just wanted to push a new view controller within the method.

If you are using a `nib` or `storyboard` and your `UITableView` instance belongs to a `UITableViewController` you could connect your `UIButton` to an action that looks like this,

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

     NewViewController *newViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
     [newViewController setSomeProperty:property];
     [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
}
```

If you are not using a `nib` or `storyboard` then you could just connect an action to the `UIButton` programmatically in your `init` method or elsewhere.

Comment: It is not the root view of a UITableViewController, but it does have a delegate and datasource. As to doing this, look at my comment for @SaintMacintosh .

Answer (score -1):

Make a custom subclass of a `UITableViewCell` and in that - add your own button. In whatever area you want.

Comment: Like I said, it is a custom cell. And like I said, there is a UIButton in it. And yes, it is a subclass. How would I go about doing what I asked in my question?